# Only fetch commit history?

Tags: git, ssh

Is it somehow possible to only fetch the commit history from a remote repository?
I've tried to pass the `--bare` option when cloning, but that seams to download the content as well.

Would it be possible to use [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCP) over the ssh protocol?

I want be able to

- run `git shortlog -se` in the end.
- work with repos from services like Github.

Comment: Why don't you want to download the whole repository?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the amounts of commits for all of my 100+ projects stored on Github. Downloading each of the repos content when I'm only need the commit history feels unnecessary and slow.

Comment: If you only need to work with Github, you might find [their API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/) useful.

Comment: @svick: I think you should add that as an answer, since I think that's as close as the questioner is going to get, if it has to work with GitHub...

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no such option in git itself. But using the git protocols, you should be able to retrieve only the commit objects, not trees or blobs. This would mean understanding how git works and using something like [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/).

Another, and probably easier, option is to use [the GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/), specifically [Repo Commits API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/). Obviously, this will only work for repos that are hosted on GitHub.

Comment: I can't find anything like `git shortlog -se` in the API. The only thing I found was how to fetch a bunch of commits.

Comment: Then i have to fetch every commit in a project, then count them. This will take much longer than just cloning the project and run `git shortlog -se`

Comment: You don't have to fetch them one by one, if I understand the documentation correctly.

Comment: I dont think I can fetch all of them in one request. I bet they use some kind of pagination :)

Comment: [They do](http://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination), but that shouldn't be a problem, I think.